# Four-way equivalence

Tags: c++, operators, equality

How do I check the equality between four variables? This is for a 3D tic-tac-toe game.

```
if (b[0][0] == b[1][0] == b[2][0] == p) { line += 1; }
```

This doesn't work as equivalent is left-to-right. I don't want to do either of the below:

```
if (b[0][0] == p && b[1][0] == p && b[2][0] == p) { line += 1; }
if ((b[0][0] == b[1][0]) && (b[1][0] == b[2][0]) && (b[2][0] == p)) { line += 1; }
```

All variables are integers, as I know with bools I can just use &&. Is there a better way? I considered:

```
if ((b[0][0] + b[1][0] + b[2][0]) == (3 * p)) { line += 1; }
```

Since `p` will be one of three values (0 for neither X or O, 1 for X, 2 for O), it would need only changing the value of O to 4 or something impossible to achieve with three 1s, 0s, or combinations thereof. But it lacks finesse.

Comment: I am only student so I'm not sure if my recommendation is a good one or not. But did you give any thought to a `switch()` statement? You could have nested cases to compensate for the ifs.

Comment: why you don't want it?

Comment: @KazRodgers I could, but there's dozens of lines with similar enough structure (it's for a 3D Tic-Tac-Toe).

Comment: Both of your replacements will work just fine (despite the redundant parentheses in the second one) and either would be a good approach.

Comment: then write a function `bool isSame(int,int,int,int)`, but otherwise there is little room for improvement

Comment: No, there is not a better way. `if (b[0][0] == p && b[1][0] == p && b[2][0] == p)` is the go-to way to write this condition.

Comment: @gator I see. What about a function that does the switch case and returns the result. Taking 4 parameters? It's how I would go about it if I had a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you've mentioned tic-tac-toe, things change a bit. Ultimately you'll be checking each column for the same value and each row for the same value. That doesn't require a long `if ... else if...` ladder. Instead, write a function to check a row:

```
bool row_matches(board b, int row, int value) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 3; ++col)
        if (b[row][col] != value)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

and write a similar function for columns. Diagonals are even simpler.

Comment: Well, it's 3D Tic-Tac-Toe, using 8 columns instead of 9 (so 38 conditional checks). I've done the lazy thing and just wrote conditionals for each possible line.

Answer (score 3):

Since 3 out of 4 variables in the question belong to one object, you can create a method to wrap it all. Something like `bool isValid(int *A, int val) {...}` and then use it in your statement like `if (isValid(b, p)) {...}`. The name is arbitrary since the wider context is not given.